# How to add class to sub menu in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to add `has-submenu` class on `li`(child item) But still not working my sub menu.

Please help me.

I want menu Like that : [I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXKze.png)

But my menu is show like that : [My Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HypQ.png)

Sample Html : [Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fWqp.png)

Header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
'theme_location'=>'primary',
'container' => 'ul',
'container_class' => 'main-menu ',
'menu_class'=>'navigation-menu', 
'link_before' => '<i class="ti-home"></i><span>', 
'link_after' => '</span>',

)); ?>
```

Function.php

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'imctheme' ) );

    //add active class in menu
    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
    function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
         if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
                 $classes[] = 'active ';  // your new class
         }
         return $classes;
    }
```

Comment: There already is a class on submenus in Wordpress..

Comment: Please Can you explain @rblarsen

Comment: The default WordPress NavWalker already adds the class `menu-item-has-children` to the parent LI in such cases.

Comment: _“Sample Html : [Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fWqp.png)”_ - that is not the HTML WordPress would create for a menu, that looks like something you just hard-coded into the template yourself …?

Comment: I was try but still not working :(

Comment: It's a bootstrap template menu.i want to bootstrap theme integrate in wordpress so..

Comment: Thank you .. Thank you .. @CBroe . My problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Header.php**

```
<div class="navbar-custom shadow">
 <div class="container">
    <div id="navigation">
       <!-- Navigation Menu-->

   <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'=>'primary',
    'depth' => 3,
    'container' => 'ul',
    'container_class' => 'main-menu ',
    'menu_class'=>'navigation-menu', 
    'link_before' => '<i class="ti-home"></i><span>', 
    'link_after' => '</span>',
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'=> new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()

    )); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Function.php**

```
// Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` function the get menu items discretely and output them however you desire. [See this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/).